# Intercambiar elementos arreglos

Tags: array, funciones, pseint

Tengo este programa que pretende intercambiar el contenido de un arreglo con otro vacío ("mudar" los elementos de un arreglo a otro). Es una implementación de un programa en SLe. El programa tira error diciendo Posición no inicializada (A1(0)).

```
Proceso intercambio
    //  Ejemplo de uso de intercambiar().
    Definir a, b, i Como Enteros;
    a <- 100;
    b <- 30;
    Dimension M[5];
    Definir M Como Entero;
    Dimension N[5];
    Definir N Como Entero;
    
    M[0]<-10;
    M[1]<-14;
    M[2]<-21;
    M[3]<-3;
    M[4]<-1;
    
    N[0]<-1;
    N[1]<-212;
    N[2]<-31;
    N[3]<-4;
    N[4]<-90;
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Antes de intercambiar: a= ", a, " b= ", b;
    
    intercambiar(a, b, 4);
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Luego de intercambiar: a= ", a, " b= ", b;
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Antes de intercambiar: ";
    Escribir "M= " Sin Saltar;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 4 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir M[i], ", " Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "N= ", Sin Saltar;
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 4 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir N[i], ", " Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    
    intercambiar(M, N, 4);
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Luego de intercambiar: ";
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "M= ", Sin Saltar;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 4 Hacer
        Escribir M[i], ", " Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "N= ", Sin Saltar;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 4 Hacer
        Escribir N[i], ", " Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    Escribir "";
FinProceso

SubProceso intercambiar(a1 Por Referencia, a2 Por Referencia, n)
    Definir i, tmp Como Enteros;
    tmp<-0;
    i<-0;
    Mientras i < n Hacer 
        tmp <- a1[i]; 
        a1[i] <- a2[i]; 
        a2[i] <- tmp;
        i <- i + 1;
    FinMientras
FinSubProceso
```

Comment: Como indica tu error a1[0] no es una posición, por lo que se deja ver en tus lineas estas ejecutando ```intercambiar(a, b, 4)```, en donde ```a``` y ```b``` no son arreglos, son enteros, por ende la posición ```a1[i]``` ni ```a2[i]``` en tu Subproceso no existe. Es ahí donde se presenta el error.

Comment: No te fijaste bien. Una cosa es la variable a y otra muy distinta es el arreglo a[1]. Igual lo cambio por otea función que solo intercambie números.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que hay varios problemas en el código que proporcioné. Me ocuparé de cada uno y proporcionaré una versión corregida del código.

1 La función intercambiar está creada para intercambiar el contenido de dos arreglos, pero está incorrectamente definida al tomar punteros a punteros (a1 Por Referencia e a2 Por Referencia). Debería tomar punteros a los primeros elementos de las matrices (a1 y a2).

2 En este programa la función intercambiar también se utiliza para intercambiar dos números enteros, pero dicha función no está diseñada para intercambiar dos variables. Se necesita crear una función separada para intercambiar dos números enteros.

3 La función intercambiar se llama con argumentos incorrectos para intercambiar dos números enteros. Se debe llamar con las direcciones de a y b, no con un tamaño de matriz de 4.

El programa corregido quedaría así:

```
Proceso intercambio
    //  Ejemplo de uso de intercambiar().
    Definir a, b, i Como Enteros;
    a <- 100;
    b <- 30;
    Dimension M[5];
    Definir M Como Entero;
    Dimension N[5];
    Definir N Como Entero;
    
    M[0]<-10;
    M[1]<-14;
    M[2]<-21;
    M[3]<-3;
    M[4]<-1;
    
    N[0]<-1;
    N[1]<-212;
    N[2]<-31;
    N[3]<-4;
    N[4]<-90;
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Antes de intercambiar: a= ", a, " b= ", b;
    
    intercambiarnumeros(a, b);
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Luego de intercambiar: a= ", a, " b= ", b;
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Antes de intercambiar: ";
    Escribir "M= " Sin Saltar;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 4 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir M[i], ", " Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "N= ", Sin Saltar;
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 4 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir N[i], ", " Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    
    intercambiararreglos(M, N, 4);
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Luego de intercambiar: ";
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "M= ", Sin Saltar;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 4 Hacer
        Escribir M[i], ", " Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "N= ", Sin Saltar;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 4 Hacer
        Escribir N[i], ", " Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    Escribir "";
FinProceso

SubProceso Intercambiarnumeros(a Por Referencia, b Por Referencia)
    Definir tmp Como Entero;
    tmp <- a;
    a <- b;
    b <- tmp;
FinSubProceso

SubProceso intercambiararreglos(a1, a2, n)
    Definir i, tmp Como Enteros;
    tmp<-0;
    i<-0;
    Mientras i < n Hacer 
        tmp <- a1[i]; 
        a1[i] <- a2[i]; 
        a2[i] <- tmp;
        i<-i+1;
    FinMientras
FinSubProceso
```